# Parameter validation errors

Tags: ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm using 0.7.0 of the Grape gem and have the following validation rules around an endpoint:

```
params do
    requires :UUID, type: String
    requires :PrimaryJobFunctionCode, type: String
    requires :PrimaryAssetClassCode, type: String
    requires :PrimaryGeographicalFocusCode, type: String
    requires :SecondaryJobFunctionCodes, type: Array
    requires :SecondaryAssetClassCodes, type: Array
    requires :SecondaryGeographicalFocusCodes, type: Array
end
post "save" do
```

The payload I'm trying to POST is:

> "{
>       "UUID":"SL1-4E6Z6DW",
>       "PrimaryJobFunctionCode":"FRUCJF:30",
>       "PrimaryAssetClassCode":"FRUCAC:34",
>       "PrimaryGeographicalFocusCode":"G:31",
>       "SecondaryJobFunctionCodes":["FRUCJF:69"],
>       "SecondaryAssetClassCodes":["FRUCAC:24"],
>       "SecondaryGeographicalFocusCodes":["G:3D"]   }"

The errors I'm getting is:

```
"UUID is missing, PrimaryJobFunctionCode is missing, PrimaryAssetClassCode is missing, PrimaryGeographicalFocusCode is missing, SecondaryJobFunctionCodes is missing, SecondaryAssetClassCodes is missing, SecondaryGeographicalFocusCodes is missing"
```

I must be missing something obvious

Comment: try use `type: Array[String]`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk afraid that didn't work - still identical error message